# How to check in yii/php if string have any disallowed HTML in it?

Tags: php, yii, htmlpurifier

In my project I use php and yii framework.
I have a predefined set of the disallowed html tags(for example - "script, object") and I need to check that entered text don't contain any of these tags.

What function I can use in order to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with potentially unsafe HTML from the client (WYSIWYG editors etc.), I'd use a library like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). It lets you to specify allowed and disallowed tags.

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to get boolean result from HTML Purifier that the string contains some disallowed tags ?

Comment: It deals with them by stripping them out and returning the safe HTML. Normally you wouldn't want to give the user an error - just store what they gave you that's valid. You could potentially compare input and output strings, but the library can also fix badly constructed HTML (invalid nesting and so on) - another one if its features, so this would be very unreliable.

Comment: Note: there is a CHtmlPurifier widget pre-built for Yii that you can use and simple instructions on running your data through it as a validation filter too ...